# Possible to repair garbled Chinese filenames?

Tags: utf-8, ftp, iconv, filezilla, big5

I'm downloading via FTP some files with chinese names (BIG5 encoded), and Filezilla displays those filenames as garbage (as FTP cannot handle any encoding other than ASCII and UTF-8, as least the standard compliant ones).

Given a filename with garbled characters, is it possible for me to repair the encoding and get a proper filename String given that I already know the source encoding? Will the FTP client misinterpreting BIG5 as UTF-8 insert bytes that make conversion back to BIG5 difficult?

My proposed steps (in Java):
1. get the garbled filename using File object.
2. getbytes using UTF-8.
3. create a new string using those bytes in BIG5.
4. Write the decoded filename back to the file.

Will the above method work?

Comment: I can, but they look like your typical garbage strings. e.g. ./202.177.28.66/org/uoind/?C?ӹΫ? (would posting a raw byte sequence help? I doubt the string itself will have all the information intact.)

Comment: If you can post the raw byte sequence it would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not every sequence of bytes is a valid ASCII or UTF-8 string so it's quite likely that some of the bytes will have been discarded, converted to the [replacement character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm), or otherwise irreversibly mangled. So it looks like you won't be able to retrieve the original filenames if they have been modified by FileZilla to become correctly formed UTF-8 or ASCII.

You might be lucky to be able to get a certain percentage of the original characters back, where they just happened to be both valid BIG5 and valid UTF-8, but I doubt you will be able to recover the entire filename.

You could post a few examples of your garbled filenames (as raw bytes encoded in hex) to get a more definite answer. That way we can see exactly what the damage is.